# Selectively checkout directories using SVNCheckout in MSBuild

Tags: svn, msbuild, tortoisesvn, msbuild-task, msbuildcommunitytasks

In my project I have many folders. I certainly know I want have changes in only around 2 directories. Also, I don't want to checkout the entire source to accomplish it. How can I implement this using MSbuild.

```
source

-- Core

-- Helper

-- Extensions

-- Themes

-- Resources
```

I want to Checkout only

```
 source

    -- Core

    -- Extensions
```

I hope I was able to make myself clear

```
    <!--
      /*
      The below target checks out complete SVN directory which I have to avoid
      */
      -->
      <Target Name="SVNCheckOut">
        <Message Text="--------------------------------------------"/>
        <Message Text="Getting latest version from:"/>
        <Message Text="$(SVN_PATH)"/>
        <Message Text="--------------------------------------------"/>               
<SvnCheckout RepositoryPath="$(SVN_PATH)"
          LocalPath="$(CheckOutPath)">
          <Output TaskParameter="Revision" PropertyName="SVNRevision" />
        </SvnCheckout>
   <Message Text="Revision       :       $(SVNRevision)"/>
</Target>
```

Any help how can I achieve this